# removeAll - modify source list

Tags: java, kotlin

In my project I use two times removeAll method. In the second time I have to use copy of the list because source list is modified by first use of the removeAll method. Is there any way to do it without doing copy of the list?

```
val apiIdListCopy: MutableList<Int> = apiIdList

apiIdList.removeAll(dbIdList)
dbIdList.removeAll(apiIdListCopy)
```

EDIT:
For future viewers I have found easier solution in Kotlin

```
val api: List<Int> = apiIdList.stream().filter{item -> !dbIdList.contains(item)}.collect(Collectors.toList())
val db: List<Int> = dbIdList.stream().filter{item -> !apiIdList.contains(item)}.collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: What is the actual problem here?

Comment: I agree. I *tried* to write an answer; but I really do not get your problem. What is the point of removing elements when you dont want to remove them?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I have edited the question

Comment: Java8 streams for filtering a list? In Kotlin? Really?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems to me that what you are really trying to achieve is to get difference between these two lists. Unless lists are very short, way you are trying to do it is extremly inefficient, due to n^2 complexity on removal.

My suggestion would be to use Set instead of List and then utilize guava Sets method:

```
SetView<Integer> onlyInApi = Sets.difference(apiIdSet, dbIdSet);
SetView<Integer> onlyInDb = Sets.difference(dbIdSet,apiIdSet);
```

This way, you are creating sets containing differences between two collections you are interested in, but without actually doing copies (as they are views and are still backed by original collections).

Above example is java, not kotlin, but conversion should be trivial.

Comment: Thank you very much! Dzięki! :)

Comment: No need for Guava here

Answer (score 1):

All you need is already provided by Kotlin:

```
val onlyInApi = apiIdList - dbIdList
val onlyInDb = dbIdList - apiIdList
```

The `-` operator works on `Iterable`, so you can apply it to lists or sets. Note that it uses sets under the hood, so it is as efficient as using Guava's `Sets.difference` as it was suggested.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I didn't know that it can be done in so much easy way.

Comment: Isn't it creating copies internally? One of the requirements was to avoid copying lists.

Comment: In case of operating on lists, it converts one list into a set, then collects the result into a new list. I believe those copings are acceptable (look at the edit of the question)